# C# - SearchOption.AllDirectories but not in certain folders

Tags: c#, subdirectory

I'd like to use this `Directory.GetFiles(source, file, SearchOption.AllDirectories))`

But do not search in specific folders.

How can I manage that? Thank you!

Comment: By not using that option and recursing through the folders manually.

Comment: Sorry I meant in certain folder, but I think your answer will be the same.

Comment: They can be excluded from the result, but there is no way to exclude them from the search without recursion

Comment: Unless the folder to exclude is directly in the source folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GetFiles` with `SearchOption.AllDirectories` will search all directories. If you aren't worried about the performance hit of searching all directories, and just want to filter the results, you can do something like this:

```
var pathsToAvoid = new List<string> { @"c:\public\temp\", @"c:\public\media\" };

var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\public\", "temp.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(filePath => !pathsToAvoid.Any(path =>
    filePath.StartsWith(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Otherwise, you would need to manually search the directories you care about one at a time.

Comment: I would prefer `EnumerateFiles` here over `GetFiles`, myself...since it's a bit more LINQ-y. Net effect is the same, obviously.